# Portal or tools to check CSS compatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I would like to know if there are any tools that we can run to check if this `CSS` code is compatible with IE11? Asking as I'm trying to fix an existing code that runs on Chrome.

Comment: [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) is one of the widely using css compatibility tool to check.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CanIUse](https://www.caniuse.com).

Type the CSS/JS property you want and the site will compare with all major browsers.

E.g. Type "Flexbox" and it will tell which browser (and their versions) supports `flexbox`